# get variable from topic with python

Tags: ros, python, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a node and subscribe a topic (nav_msgs/Odometry Message) i want operate with the quaternion, how i can get it value? With python

i try it this way:

```
rospy.Subscriber('/odometry/filtered', Odometry) 
x = Odometry.pose.pose.pose.orientation.x
```

but not work well

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209558/get-variable-from-topic-with-python/) by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2015-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, your subscriber must use a callback, I suggest trying the [ROS publisher subscriber tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29#rospy_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.Writing_the_Subscriber_Node).

I suppose you want to get the orientation in the Euler angle format (rotations around the x-y-z axis). Once you're able to receive the message through the callback, you can use the following code to access the angles.

```
import tf
orientation_euler = tf.transformations.euler_from_quaternion( odom_msg.pose.pose.orientation)
# use the angles with orientation_euler.x, orientation_euler.y, orientation_euler.z
```

---

Originally posted by [yohtm](https://answers.ros.org/users/22234/yohtm/) with karma: 66 on 2015-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2